# Setting Image of TableView Cell NSURL isResizable error

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using some regex expression to get the first URL in an xml which is a link to a photo, and set that photo as the cell's imageview image.  Here is my code:

```
NSString *thearticleImage = entry.articleImage;
    NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
    NSString *someString = thearticleImage;
    self.theurl = [someString substringWithRange:[expression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])]];


    cell.imageView.image = [NSURL URLWithString:theurl];
```

I end up gettin the error:

```
'-[NSURL _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x882e250'
```

What is the issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use url to `imageView.image` so you can use this like below

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your image link"]];
UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
cell.imageView.image = downloadedImage;
```

But it will produce crash...

**NOTE**

To overcome with this crash you must hit the URL asynchronously .BY this it will not produce crash and table will freely scroll